# When i run Visual Studio 2010 web application, i am getting "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When i run Visual Studio 2010 web application, i am getting

> "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

I am using Visual Studio Development Server (meaning ASP .NET development server not using IIS) . And also i have made changes in host file as well (127.0.0.1       localhost ). Can any one help me on this?
I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Comment: This may be due to an internal server error (HTTP 500 error). Put a break point on the Page_Load event on your main page and see where it might be breaking.

Comment: @CameronTinker. Break point also not works for me...:(

Comment: what change did you make to your host file??

Comment: @Darren: In host file i have removed the "#" before 127.0.0.1 localhost . Bcoz i have found this is one of the solution for this issue. But its not workedout for me.

Comment: In IE (or a real browser), open the developer tools and look at the network request that's going out. That may give you more insight into the request and response, and hopefully details on the actual error.

Comment: @JoeEnos: when i use developer tools, i am getting result as "Aborted".

Comment: If you create a brand new empty ASP.NET app and run it, does that work? If so, then your hosts file and network stuff is probably fine, and it would be something in your app. If that's the case, then look for things like handlers in your Global.asax, or modules in your web.config.

Comment: @JoeEnos: Its a new empty ASP.NET app only. i checked both Global.asax and web.config aswell. Both looks fine.

Comment: If it's happening on an empty app, then you won't find anything useful in Global or web.config. Do you have any weird proxy or firewall stuff?

Comment: @JoeEnos : No.. we don't have weird proxy or firewall. I am not clear about weird proxy. But in host file some reverse proxy is enabled. Is this creating any problem??

Comment: I haven't worked with reverse proxies before, so I don't know - but it's a definite possibility. If you're able to remove or disable that, I'd say give it a shot, and see what happens.

Comment: @JoeEnos : Still getting the same error... :(... anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi.. Finally i fixed the issue. By unchecking the Bypass proxy setting in the internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an entry to the **LMHOSTS** file:

"127.0.0.1  localhost"

Comment: let me know where can i find this file. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise operating system.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMHOSTS#Windows_NT_4.0.2C_Windows_2000.2C_Windows_XP.2C_Vista.2C_7.2C_Windows_Server_2003.2C_Windows_Server_2008_and_Windows_Server_2008_R2

Comment: there isn't one by default, I was just guessing, since I had similar problems. If you're interested check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977602.aspx

Comment: @silverchair :  After makes the changes in LMHOSTS also, i am getting the same problem.

Comment: Hi.. Finally i fixed the issue. By unchecking the Bypass proxy setting in the internet explorer.